# For a function $f:A->B$ show f(X-Y)=f(X)-f(Y) $\implies$ f is injective where $X,Y$ subset of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

Attempt:

$a\in f(X-Y)\implies a=f(b)$ for some $b\in X, b\notin Y$.
$a\in f(X)-f(Y)\implies a=f(c),a\neq f(d)$ for some $c\in X, d\in Y$

so $a=f(b)=f(c)\neq f(d)$.

Use contrapositive of injective definition:

suppose $c\neq d$, show $f(c)\neq f(d)$.

But suppose the opposite, $f(c)=f(d)$,but this is a contradiction of $f(c)=f(d)$ above.

Did I do this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is not so clear, did a little mess with quantification and order of assumptions. Try this: let $x\in A$ then $\emptyset\neq f(\{x\})=f(\{x\}\setminus (A\setminus\{x\}))=f(\{x\})\setminus f(A\setminus\{x\})=\{f(x)\}\setminus f(A\setminus\{x\})$ so it can't be $f(x)\in f(A\setminus\{x\})$ (id est $x$ is the only point on which $f$ assume the value $f(x)$)